# in j2ee any change in web.xml result in ERROR:-Server apache-tomcat-8.0.35 at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Unable to add `<filter>` in **web.xml** in eclipse mars`(ERROR:-Server apache-tomcat-8.0.35 at localhost failed to start.)`.The server being used is `tomcat-8.0.35` ,Any kind of change in **web.xml** results in `ERROR:-Server apache-tomcat-8.0.35 at localhost failed to start.`

**Message shown in console window is**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316) 
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821) 
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534) at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023) 
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877) 
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: What changes you did in web.xml?

Comment: i added servlet and servlet-mapping..
i also added filter and filter-mapping

Comment: Show us the resulting file.